# perl regex to match ""(string) syntax

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am new to Perl and regex and I need to extract all the strings from a text file. A string is identified by anything that is wrapped by double quotes.

Example of string:

```
"This is string"
"1!=2"
"This is \"string\""
"string1"."string2"
"S
t
r
i
n
g"
```

The code:

```
my $fh;

open($fh,'<','text.txt') or die "$!";

undef $/;
my $text = <$fh>;

my @strings = m/".*"/g; # this returns the most out "" in example 4
my @strings2 = m/"[^"]*"/g #fixed the above issue but does not take in example 3
```

Edited : I want to get (1) a double quote, followed by (2) zero or more occurrences of either a non-double-quote-non-backslash or a backslash followed by any character, followed by (3) a double quote. (2) can be anything but "

The regex provided below m/"(?:\.|[^"])*"/g however when the there is a line with `"string1".string2."string2"` it will return `"string1" string2 "string3"`

Is there any wher to skip the previously matched word?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Note that what you want is (1) a double quote, followed by (2) zero or more occurrences of either a non-double-quote-non-backslash or a backslash followed by any character, followed by (3) a double quote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
/"(?:\\.|[^"])*"/
```

[image]

... that reads as:

- match double quotation mark,
- followed by any number of...

  --- either any escaped character (any symbol prepended by `\`)

  --- or any character that's not a double quotation mark
- followed by double quotation mark

The key trick here is using alternation that'll eat *any* escaped symbol - including escaped double quotation mark.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/129155).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it is working now..!! I was not aware of ?: in perl regex before this. Can anyone explain what is that or direct me a source? Thank you!

Comment: It's used to mark a so-called `non-capturing group` - when you need just to group series of expression in a pattern, but not to store the result of this grouping. I'd recommend checking [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Have a much better idea on how the non-capturing group works now.

I found the the above does not work if there is `"string1".$string2."string3"`, it will return `"string1" string2 string3`

Is it possible to skip the previously match charater in perl regex?

Comment: In `"string1".$string2."string3"` both `"string1"` and `"string3"` are matched, if you use the pattern correctly. [Proof](http://regex101.com/r/oB0aD7).

Comment: Thanks raina77ow!! 
A typing error in the regex causes lots of unreasonable results