# perl script help to replace words in double quotes

Tags: perl

I need some help with the perl script. I basically want to read each line a file (each line will have one word enclosed within double quotes) and replace that word.

For example:

here are the content of the file:

```
"word 1" some string contents
"word 2" some string contents
"word 3" some string contents.
```

how to replace word 1, word 2, and word 3 in each line..?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

thanks,

Comment: Can you have escaped quotes inside your quotes? If not, then it's as simple as `s/"[^"]*"/replace me/`

Comment: And if not, it's simple as well: `s/"(?:\\.|[^"])*"//g` But this question is quite unclear: what should be the replacement, should only the first such word in each line be replaced etc.

Comment: 7 hours ago someone asked a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754913/perl-regex-to-match-string-syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one-liner for this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^"[^"]*"/<replacement>/g' <filename>
```

it isn't really clear from your question what are you replacing with, so just fill in the blanks.